# Monitor Facebook newsfeed for keywords

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I would like to monitor my Facebook newsfeed for keywords in status updates (web developer, wordpress, php, etc...).

My questions are:

1) Does anyone know how I can get just status updates this in JSON format via the facebook Open Graph? (not /me/home, only status updates)

2) Does something like this already exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Realtime Updates API and look for changes for the "feed" connection. Have a look at the docs here.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/

Be aware that if you receive a notification, you actively need to pull the fead data by issueing

```
GET /me/feed?since=LAST_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP
```

where LAST_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP is the timestamp when you pulled it for the last time (you should store this in your application).

Comment: I'm looking for specifically status update, not the entire feed, and not the user's status updates.  For instance, I want to monitor all of my friend's statuses for the word 'web developer'

Comment: Well, this is not possible via the Graph API. As far as I know you can only monitor your own newsfeed, not the complete status updates of your friends. Your newsfeed will be subject to the EdgeRank filtering, so you can't be sure whether you see all updates